# Define the variable for counting the total amount of prime numbers at the very beginning of the code

Tags: javascript

Im having a classic problem with the prime numbers. I get the code to print the numbers from 0-60. But idk how the get the total amount in the end.

*Edit. Im a complete beginner and started learning JS in a web school. I just need guidance on how to solve problem. How should the counting variable be defined?

```js
for (var counter = 2; counter <= 60; counter++) {
  var notPrime = false;
  for (var i = 2; i <= counter; i++) {
    if (counter % i === 0 && i !== counter) {
      notPrime = true;
    }
  }
  if (notPrime === false) {
    console.log(counter);
    //Here I should get ; "Total of prime numbers found: 17"
  }
}
```

Comment: You should break out of the loop when you set `notPrime`

Comment: "Define the variable for counting the total amount of prime numbers at the very beginning of the code." Unironically, the answer is in the question. Create a variable outside, and increment the variable every time you find a prime.

Answer (score 0):

`counter` isn't a counter, it's the numbers you're testing for being prime. Use another variable for counting the primes.

The line that prints the total number of primes should be after the loop, not inside the loop.

You can also simplify the code. Change the inner loop condition to `<`, then you don't have to check `&& i !== counter`.

And boolean variables are easier to use if you don't give them negative names.

```js
let counter = 0;
for (var number = 2; number <= 60; number++) {
  var prime = true;
  for (var i = 2; i < number; i++) {
    if (number % i === 0) {
      prime = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (prime) {
    counter++;
    console.log(`${number} is prime`);
  }
}
console.log(`Total number of primes = ${counter}`);
```

Comment: But doesnt this print total number of primes after every number? I need to get it once in the end.

Comment: That line isn't in the loop.

Comment: Did you try running it? How many times did it print the total number of primes?

Answer (score 0):

You should keep track of the prime numbers which are found at the end of your foor loop.

```js
let total = 0

for (var counter = 2; counter <= 60; counter++) {
  var notPrime = false;
  for (var i = 2; i <= counter; i++) {
    if (counter % i === 0 && i !== counter) {
      notPrime = true;
    }
  }
  if (notPrime === false) {
      total++
  }
}

//Here I should get ; "Total of prime numbers found: 17"
console.log("Total of prime numbers found:", total)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create an empty array and push the your prime numbers at the end of each iteration. Then when all the iterations are done. The length of the array with be the total number of prime numbers.

```js
var primeNumbers = []
for (var counter = 2; counter <= 60; counter++) {
  var notPrime = false;
  for (var i = 2; i <= counter; i++) {
    if (counter % i === 0 && i !== counter) {
      notPrime = true;
    }
  }
  if (notPrime === false) {
    console.log(counter);
    
    //push the numbers into the primeNumbers array
    primeNumbers.push(counter);
    //Here I should get ; "Total of prime numbers found: 17"
  }
}
// After all the iterations are done you can get the total by using .length property of arrays.
console.log(primeNumbers.length, 'prime numbers found')
```

I hope this helps...